# Does anyone know/have a library for handling strings in C++ like PHP?

Tags: c++, c

Been searching around for something like this, and was wondering if it even exists.  The way C++ handles strings is bothersome and not very intuitive.  It'd be nice to be able to manipulate strings within C/C++ the same way you can in PHP/

Comment: I'm not sure how PHP does it, but there's `std::string`. Granted the C way is tedious, the C++ way is definitely not.

Comment: Are you using `const char*` or `std::string`?

Comment: C or C++? Those are different beasts.

Comment: `std::string` comes pretty close. The only notable abstraction leak is that you'll sometimes have to explicitly construct `string`s over string literals. And there's no variable substitution in C++ strings, for that you nead `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev, First problem almost solved: User-defined literals in C++11: `str = "part 1"_s + "part 2";`

Comment: Currently using std::string, and it's OK I suppose.  Was just wondering if there was a more automated library.  For instance, adding a number to a string in php is pretty easy $var = "Whatever " . $num;  It gets a bit more complicated in C/C++.  :(

Comment: @AndrewBurgess, Again, user-defined literals can perform int->string conversions for use like: `string s = 12345_s`, making it really easy, but you can always implement an `itos` function.

Answer (score 3):

Although not exact, this has proven useful to me in the past.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/string_algo.html

Hope it helps.